# By or from in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

I am subtitling a romantic song on YouTube, literally translating the  expression given below from Hindi to English

Literal translation:

> “I don’t have the leisure from loving you for you are in my arm.”

In my mother tongue that describes: “I don’t have the leisure because of loving you for you are in my arm.”, so which one is fine to use from or by in the sense of because of?

Comment: Your sentences are both very confusing. "Leisure" does not take an article. I *think* they are both saying "I am not free, because I love you, because you are in my arms" but maybe it's actually "I have not stopped loving you, because you are in my arms." I don't quite understand.

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, which is specifically against the rules of the site. If you have a question about some particular part of the sentence, then please ask a new question about that, and include the work you've already done to try and answer it on your own. [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To address the direct question at the end, I'm not sure that either "from" or "because of" is the best translation. I hope you can clarify, but I *suspect* the sentiment translated as "leisure" is something along the lines of "my love won't let me rest." Sometimes in translation one gets the most idiomatic results by rearranging the word order, like "My love for you won't let me rest until you are in my arms." But I'm making a lot of assumptions there about intended meaning.